# Pass Parameter To Algolia React Instant SearchBox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia

I am building a website with React and I am using algolia instantsearch on it. I have managed to create a search page which shows all results and filters by search. I want to use an external search input from a different page on the instant search.

What I would like is the search results page to appear already filtered by the search input parameter. I already create a page like (https://url/search/q=name) but the results page isn’t taking the parameter. The instant search displays all the results.

How can I achieve this? Any recommendations or links i can read will be appreciated.

My code looks like this :

```
import algoliasearch from "algoliasearch/lite";

var url_string = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;

var url = new URL(url_string);

var q = url.searchParams.get("q");

const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
);

function BusinessesSection({ busData }) {

  var stateMapping = {
    stateToRoute(uiState) {
      const indexUiState = uiState['Test'];
      return {
        query: indexUiState.query,
        page: indexUiState.page,
        // ...
      };
    },
  
    routeToState(routeState) {
      return {
        ['Test']: {
          query: routeState.query,
          page: routeState.page,
          // ...
        },
      };
    },
  };

  const Hit = ({ hit }) => (
    <Item.Group divided key={hit.id}>
      <Item fluid>
          
        <Item.Header> {hit.name} </Item.Header>
        <Item.Description> {hit.business_json.description} </Item.Description>

        <Button onClick={() => { handleSingle(hit);}}> View More </Button>
      </Item>
    </Item.Group>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <InstantSearch
        searchClient={searchClient}
        indexName="Test"
        routing = {
          stateMapping = function (uiState) {
            return {
              q: uiState['Test'].query,
            }
          },
          stateMapping.routeToState = function (routeState) {
            return {
              query: routeState.q
            }
          }
        }
      >
      
      </InstantSearch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(BusinessesSection);
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a default search in a search box, one can use the `defaultRefinement` parameter on the SearchBox widget of React InstantSearch.
You can add in here the value of your external search input, and then it will work out of the box.

```
<SearchBox
    defaultRefinement={q}
    translations={{
    placeholder: "Search …"
}}
```

The defaultRefinement is a string